# The function such that $\ln(e^z)=z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis we have that:
$$\ln(e^z)=z+2\pi n i$$
in general. Is there a way to define a function such that:
$$\ln(e^z)=z \ \ \forall \ \  z$$
I know an obvious candidate would be the principal value logarithm, however in such case we have $n$ such that $2\pi n+Im(z) \in [-\pi,\pi]$ which is generically not the same as I have given above.

Comment: That would be difficult, since the exponential function isn't injective on $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: Since $e^0 = e^{2\pi i}$ your *function* would have to send the same value ($1$ in this example) to different values

Comment: To sum up previous two comments: there is no such function.